# Question mark on Github README page

Tags: github, markdown

Why question mark appears on Github instead of the actual link?
[image]

My README file is like this:

```
## Refer to ![handout](handout2.pdf) for more detailed instructions
```

`handout2.pdf` is present in the same folder.

Note: clicking on the question mark does lead to the right page, it is just the problem of incorrect symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Markdown for an inline image, that is, an HTML `<img>` tag:

```
![handout](handout2.pdf)
```

Since PDFs can't be rendered inline, the browser shows an error placeholder.

This is Markdown for an inline link, that is, an HTML `<a>` tag:

```
[handout](handout2.pdf)
```

Remove the `!` and you should be fine.

See the [Github Guide to Mastering Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) for more.